# Looking for a "Thread.sleep like" method that cannot be interrupted

Tags: java

For unit tests purposes, I'm looking for a method to pause for certain duration but that cannot be interrupted. The purpose is exactly to test interrupt() on my thread code.

Comment: [`Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html), from Guava. If you don't want to depend on Guava, it's pretty straightforward to reimplement.

Comment: Side note, might help or not: I try to really avoid threads by now; instead I turn to ExectorServices ... because: it is very simply to generate a "same thread" executor service for testing. And all of a sudden, a lot of multi-threaded code can be tested in a straight forward single-threaded environment.